# $.post javascript function in loop

Tags: javascript, post

I am writing a code in which user checks multiple check boxes and those users assign to the selected division. I am using $.post function in a loop of check boxes. Everything is working fine and checked users are being assigned to the selected division. Now, the issue is that I want to print a response after $.post function but everything I write after this post function, javascript executes it before that function and that's why, I am unable to print the response. Please check the below code for your convenience and suggest a possible solution.

Thanks a lot

```
function assign_user(div_id){
    //alert(div_id);
    var favorite = [];
    $.each($("input[name='user']:checked"), function(){
        value = $(this).val();
        $.post("../db/assign_user.php",{div_id:div_id,value:value}, 
        function(x){

        });
// I want to print final response here but it executes before post function
    });
}
```

Comment: print what response?

Comment: Like an alert success message

Comment: you'll have to wait until the success message exists. you haven't provided code that even attempts to print the message, so... we have no idea what you are actually doing wrong, all we can do is guess.

Comment: basically the alert message is executing before post function

Comment: well, no, it's executing after the post function, but before the post request has completed.

Comment: function assign_user(div_id){
    //alert(div_id);
    var favorite = [];
    $.each($("input[name='user']:checked"), function(){
        value = $(this).val();
        $.post("../db/assign_user.php",{div_id:div_id,value:value}, 
        function(x){
            result = x;
        });
if(result=='Success'){
 alert(result);
}
 });
}

Comment: You mean print the final `x` from post's success function?

Comment: I want to do like the recent code i sent

Comment: just forget the print message now and kindly tell me if I want to reload page after getting success messages from post, how to do that?

Comment: @linux, yes final print message after the whole post function is executed

Comment: any answer please

Answer (score -1):

`Ajax` requests are asynchronous. They are sent to the server, then the javascript continues on without waiting for a response. If you type your `Ajax` request like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "../db/assign_user.php",
  type: 'POST', 
  data: {div_id:div_id,value:value}, 
  success: function(data){ 
    alert(data); 
  }
});
```

then in the `success` function, you can handle or alert the response.